# Population in a Galton Watson process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-process, branching-rules

Consider a Galton-Watson process, $W_0$, $W_1$, $W_2$ $\ldots$, where
$W_0=1$ and the next random variables are defined by the following recursion,
$$
W_t = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{W_{t-1}} \xi_i,
$$
where $\xi_i$ are independent and identical non negative random variables. It is well known that if $E[\xi]<1$, then the process is subcritical, meaning that there exists a $C < 1 $ such that  $P(\tau > k) \leq C^k$, where $\tau = \inf \{t \, : \, W_t = \emptyset \}$. This means that the process dies out exponentially fast.

Where can I find a proof that under the same hypothesis there exists a $C<1$ such that 
$$
P ( \sum\limits_{i=0}^{\tau} W_i > k ) < C^k,
$$
i.e., not only the survival time $\tau$ decays exponentially fast but also the total number of individual of the process?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you able to show the identity $\mathbb{E}[e^{\lambda \sum_{i=1}^nW_i}]=e^{\phi_n(\lambda)}$, which the answer you accepted uses crucially?

Comment: Yes I am able to show such identity. Are you able to show it? (I am asking just out of curiosity). In case you are not, you should just recall the properties of characteristic functions and work a bit with them...

Comment: Trying to be insulting, are you? But the try is so laborious that it is not even entertaining...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\phi(\lambda)=\ln\mathbb{E}[e^{\lambda \xi_1}]$ assuming it exists for $\lambda >0$

And $\phi_n(\lambda)$ defined as $\phi_{1}(\lambda)=\phi(\lambda)$ and $\phi_{n+1}(\lambda)=\phi(\lambda + \phi_{n}(\lambda))$

Then:

$$\mathbb{E}\left[e^{\lambda \sum_{i=1}^nW_i}\right]=e^{\phi_n(\lambda)}$$

thus,

$$\mathbb{E}\left[e^{\lambda \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}W_i}\right]=e^{\phi_{\infty}(\lambda)}$$
where $\phi_{\infty}(\lambda)=\phi(\lambda + \phi_{\infty}(\lambda))$.

because $\phi'(0)=\mathbb{E}[\xi_1]<1$ for $\lambda>\lambda' >0$ small enough, $\phi_{\infty}(\lambda')$ will be defined and thus, you have what you want by Markov's inequality:

$$\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty W_i>k\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(e^{\lambda'\sum_{i=1}^\infty W_i}\geq e^{\lambda'k}\right)\leq e^{\phi_{\infty}(\lambda')}e^{-\lambda' k}$$